# Remove all folder name form url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Recently I have installed my site into a sub-folder of root of server.

So To remove folders name from URL i have used following htaccess code.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?hostname.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ user/site1/index.php [L]
```

But the **problem** is  that  i am, also able to access my site
Via

**hostname.com/user/site1**

How can i stop user accessing my site via  "hostname.com/user/site1"

Please help

Comment: See this :https://helponnet.com/2021/11/30/remove-folder-name-from-url/

Answer (score 1):

You can have a new redirect rule for this:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /user/site1(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?hostname\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ user/site1/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Not working I am still able to access site using
hostname.com/user/site1

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located? Check my edited rule.

Comment: at root i.e.  /.htaccess